# Mongodb retrieve correct json from geospatial query php

Tags: php, android, json, mongodb, jsonlint

I'm tring to retrieve correct JSON from this code.

```
$query = array( 'loc' => array('$geoWithin' => array('$centerSphere' => array(array($x,$y), 35 / 6371) )));
    $cursor = $collection->find($query);

    // How many results found
    $num_docs = $cursor->count();

    if( $num_docs > 0 )
        {
          foreach($cursor as $doc['punti'])
               echo json_encode($doc);
            }
        }
    else
    {
        echo "NO LOCATION \n";
    }
```

if i try to validate result in http://jsonlint.com/ it shows error.

i'll post the result of query:

```
{
    "punti": {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "551fb585ecba12c819000032"
        },
        "nome": "Google",
        "loc": [
            -122.083983,
            37.422969
        ],
        "icona": 1,
        "istituzione_id": {
            "$id": "551fb556ecba12c819000031"
        }
    }
}{
    "punti": {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "5520fe2becba12c003000029"
        },
        "nome": "Oracle",
        "loc": [
            -122.262168,
            37.531595
        ],
        "icona": 1,
        "istituzione_id": {
            "$id": "551fb556ecba12c819000031"
        }
    }
}
```

the error in JSONLint is about:

```
Parse error on line 16:
...1"        }    }}{    "punti": {   
--------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

I've tried different ways, without reaching any solution.Can Someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the tool to validate and share data via link, please use this tool to validate and if it's invalid, share here or to your friends to get help http://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidate